# Can I use multiple entries visa for multiple visits each year?

Tags: visas, canada, multiple-entry, repeat-visits

I submitted an visa application to visit my Canadian in-laws for 6 months only from Feb to Jul 2022. I just got approved and given a V-1 (Visitor) visa for Canada and it only says it's issued on Nov 2021 and valid until 2026 and it belongs to "Multiple" category.

I am a bit confused on what [the website says](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16)

> While valid, a multiple entry visa will let you travel to Canada for six months at a time as many times as you want. It will be valid for up to 10 years or one month before your passport expires, whichever is shorter

My question is:

- Is this visa always valid until 2026, or once I first enter Canada, it would expire after 6 months?
- Is the scenario valid for my visa: Can I visit my in-laws each year until 2026, as long as each stay is under 6 months?

Sorry if it's a basic question but I can't find what I need anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this visa always valid until 2026, or once I first enter Canada, it would expire after 6 months?

As a multiple-entry visa, it will remain valid for entry until the end of the expiry date on the visa in 2026. Unless you become inadmissible and your visa is revoked, you are entitled to request entry to Canada on or before that date. As its name implies, it is valid for more than one entries so it does not cease to be valid after one entry.

> You must arrive in Canada on or before the expiry date on your visa.
>
> https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16

You can enter with the visa on the last day of its validity and still be authorized to visit Canada for up to six months (at the officer's discretion).

---

> Is the scenario valid for my visa: Can I visit my in-laws each year until 2026, as long as each stay is under 6 months?

Basically yes, but your admission into Canada and the authorized period of stay are ultimately the decision of the border agent processing your request.

It is important to remember that other than Canadian citizens, permanent residents and registered "Indians", no one has the *right* to enter Canada. The visa only entitles you to seek entry into Canada at a port of entry (e.g. airport). The agent will then decide if you will be permitted into Canada and how long you are authorized to stay.

Usually, a six-month period is permitted for most visitors. However, if the agent has doubts on your financial ability, if the stated intention of your visit is short, if you return to Canada soon after you left, or if your passport is expiring soon, the agent may fix a shorter period of authorized stay. If your authorized period of stay is less (or more) than six months, this information will be provided to you at the entry.

The agent is also empowered to deny you entry if they suspect that you will not leave Canada at the end of your authorized stay or will not abide other conditions (e.g. not to study or work in Canada). Frequent travel for long periods without a good reason may raise suspicions in this regard; but once a year to visit families are almost certainly fine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that's very helpful. Just a bit confused because my application was very simple and was just asking for a 6-month visit.

Comment: @LukeVo Ah, the norm now for Canadian visa is to issue a 10-year multiple entry ones (or up to passport expiry) unless there are particular reasons to issue a short term one.